# Appending a div element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to jQuery and I am practicing appending div elements. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Div Id</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
    document.body.onload = addElement;

    function addElement () { 
        // create a new div element 
        // and give it some content 
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
        var newContent = document.createTextNode("This is a first division"); 
        newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 

        // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
        var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
        document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="div1">This is a second division.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output would be:

```
This is a second division.
```

But as per my implementation the output should be

```
This is a first division
This is a second division.
```

I am not able to figure where it is going wrong. Please someone help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is jquery here? you are using plain javascript

Comment: FYI the second `script` tag should either be inside the `head` element, or just before the `</body>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` is a property of the `window` object, not the `document.body` object.

This works:

```
window.onload = addElement;
```

Answer (score 1):

actually it works.... try to move your javascript in the head of you html file

```js
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement () { 
  // create a new div element 
  // and give it some content 
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("This is a first division"); 
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">This is a second division.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div1').before('<div id=div0>This is a first division</div>')
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yx91j8he/)

If you want Jquery it is as simple as this.

Comment: It's a valid solution using jQuery as the Q stated. Get my +1 to mitigate those unreasonable downvotes!

Comment: as i shall do to your answer. people just down vote with out even explanation.

Comment: Indeed: the Q says "I am new to jQuery and I am practicing appending div elements." so both approaches are totally correct and pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery you can check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfsq3gex/):

```
$('body').prepend('<div>This is a first division</div>');
```

Comment: Stop suggestion jQuery for every baby task

Comment: @noa-dev OP wants Jquery it is stated.

Comment: @noa-dev OS said "I am new to jQuery and I am practicing appending div elements." so my answer is in that direction.